# bytes transferred in Chrome's network tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, networking, google-chrome-devtools, web-developer-toolbar

How should I read the following from Chrome's Network tab (in developer tools):

[image]

My guess is: 1114 requests, 2.9 MB transferred over the network, the remaining till 5.2 MB (i.e. 5.2 - 2.9 = 2.3 MB) were found in the browser's cache and did not result in any kind of network activity whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, but also `transferred` measures the compressed size, so it may be smaller even if not cached.

Comment: @wOxxOm is there a way to see the volume of cached resource requests that generated no traffic at all?